# Why page views number for a page is much greater than page entrances

Tags: google-analytics

GA shows me some weird statistics, it has for some pages 20k PV for just 40 entries (cf pj).
Is this normal or just a tracking bug ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Entrances are the number of instance the user have entered your site through that page.**

**While pageviews are captured everytime that page is accessed by user via any channel.**

So that depends upon how your site is indexed and user's behavior on your site.

And also it depends on page to page(but it is obvious that **Entrances >> Pageviews**)

For example: the entrance on home page of your site might be very high and on that page there is a linked page best offers which is not that well indexed in google for the user to enter directly to that.

So pageviews of that page will be very high and entrance might be very low.

So this is the default behavior.

Comment: So there's nothing to worry about ?

Comment: No not at all...

Comment: i found in my access log that all links those pages had the same user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Evaliant; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" , it could be a botcrawler ?

Comment: I don't think this is a bot attack...Also you should not worry about entrances on a page. This is a just a indicator nothing else. If you are worried about SEO traffic..you can check sessions and source medium as Google organic..all depends what you want to track and use